# Using Python for webscraping, how to use previous session/cookie/login context to goto https://finance.yahoo.com/ to scrape my stock portfolio details

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am new to session/cookie concepts. I am trying to browse https://finance.yahoo.com/portfolios to webscrape my portfolio details using python/selenium. When I normally try to access this page, it remembers my previous login details and goes straight to my portfolio page. However if I access the same page using selenium/webdriver, it does not show my portfolio details and it is blank.
Any suggestions/guidance for accomplishing this? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get the cookies from selenium, when accessing a page, you should use:
`driver.get_cookies()`
To add cookies in selenium you can use:
`driver.add_cookie()`

An option to log in could be going on the login page via selenium, filling in the info and logging in using selenium...
However, if you don't want that, I don't believe just setting the same cookies will be enough to fix your problem. What you should do instead is use the google chrome profile from the browser where you're logged in, using this:
`option.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/path/to/your/logged-in/chrome/profile')`